# What is the underlying logic when comparing strings?

Tags: r, string

What is the logic used by R to end up with the output FALSE in the below logical operation on characters. Is it just comparing letter S with letter T instead of the entire string.

`"Sachin" > "Tendulkar"
Output: FALSE`

Comment: See under `?Comparison` for details about how strings are compared.  Tricky to say the least.

Comment: @BryanHanson, I agree *potentially* tricky, but this example seems straightforward.  With no special characters, etc., should come out the same in almost any locale setting ... ??

Comment: What's the context for the question?  Are you simply trying to find position in an alphabetic sequence?  There are better tools for that if you'll be doing it a lot.  And is this for a package?  You'll need to worry about your users encodings and locale in that case.  Otherwise, @BenBolker has you covered.

Comment: @BryanHanson there is no context, I was just trying hands on with R and I wanted to know for sure the logic involved inferring FALSE as an answer. Just intrigued!

Comment: In which programming language would the comparison lead to a different output in this case? C++ yields the same.

Comment: Same  output in Python, too. I think this is a standard comparison for basically any modern programming language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is in the documentation.  `?">"` gives:

> Comparison of strings in character vectors is lexicographic within the strings using the collating sequence of the locale in use

In other words, this is just a regular dictionary-style comparison. Things can get very complicated/weird depending on locales (e.g. how non-alphabetic, accented, upper/vs lower case, etc. etc. characters are handled), but this case looks straightforward. "S" comes before "T" in every locale I can imagine, so `"S"<"T"`; in a lexicographic sort, this will determine the order (otherwise ties would be broken by later letters in the sequence).